# PHP - if(isset($_POST['button1'')){... if(isset($_POST['button2'])).. not working?

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

I have this code:

```
   echo'<form method="POST" action="">';

    echo'Code:<input type="text" name="name">';
    echo'<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">';

    echo'</form>';

if(isset($_POST['save'])){

    //something
    echo'<form method="POST" action="">';

    echo'Code:<input type="text" name="name">';
    echo'<input type="submit" name="delh" value="Delete">';

    echo'</form>';

    if(isset($_POST['delh'])){
        // Cant show this! :(
        echo "Deleted!";

    }
}
```

When i press "DELETE", the page reloads and the message "Deleted!" remains hidden.

---

This is a schedule. The idea is if someone presses the Save button but has already saved an hour it says "You have already saved an hour, do you want to cancel it?". When it clicks "Delete", the hour is deleted from the database.

In the case where the Save button is pressed, but the person has not saved an hour, the delete button is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
echo "Deleted!";
```

Can only be reached if *both* of these conditions are true:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    //...
    if(isset($_POST['delh'])){
```

But the form you're showing contains no element named `save`.  The first condition is `false`, so the code inside that `if` block never runs.  (It may have been `true` in a *previous* request, but not in the request you're making with this form.)

You may have meant to separate those conditions?:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    //...
}

if(isset($_POST['delh'])){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Now there is a save but no delete :-(

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! I have another html form before the "isset($_POST['save'])". (There are two forms!)

This is a schedule. The idea is if someone presses the Save button but has already saved an hour it says "You have already saved an hour, do you want to cancel it?". When it clicks "Delete", the hour is deleted from the database.

In the case where the Save button is pressed, but the person has not saved an hour, the delete button is not displayed.

Comment: @NikolayBelobradov: Well, you're mostly describing whatever is in `//something` at this point.  But that's not the problem you're facing.  The logic you wrote requires *both* `save` and `delh` to be present in order to reach the "delete" code.  But the form for deleting has no `save` value.  You would either need to add a `save` element to that form or change the server-side logic to only look for the `delh` form value.  This answer tries the latter.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be something like this.
This makes use of the fact that you can open and close PHP tags anywhere.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["delh"])) { ?>
    <p>Deleted!</p>
<?php } ?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    Code:<input type="text" name="name">
    <?php if (isset($_POST["save"])) { ?>
        <input type="submit" name="delh" value="Delete" />
    <?php } elseif (isset($_POST["delh"])) { ?>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```